# Back-to-back assignments in C

Tags: c

I came across this code today:

```
for (i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    a[i] = b[i] = c[i] = 0;
}
```

What is the meaning of the code located inside the for loop?

Comment: assigned rightmost first

Comment: These are called "assignments", not "definitions".

Comment: @aschepler edited. That is correct.

Comment: Too bad this post did not show the declaration of `a[], b[], c[]` as that can make a difference.

Comment: @chux: Neither does the dup :-(. That's why I think a comprehensive answer should be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 a[i] = b[i] = c[i] = 0;
```

is parsed as:

```
 a[i] = (b[i] = (c[i] = 0));
```

and has the same effect as:

```
 a[i] = 0;
 b[i] = 0;
 c[i] = 0;
```

Comment: There aren't any sequence points in direct assignments, unlike in the bottom example. Therefore not strictly equivalent.

Comment: The equivalence you mention is technically not quite correct. (but has the same effect as if it were). For `a = b = c = 0` the equivalence is `c=0; b=c; a=b;` (and also accepting @2501's explanation of not quite equivalent)

Comment: They are also not equivalent for `volatile` qualified lvalues for the LHS of all but the leftmost assignment. And they also might not have the "same effect".

Comment: @Olaf It's quite obvious. So, if you are going to take exception to "same effect" and downvote, I am fine with it.

Comment: @P.P.: For `volatile` lvalues, this is a very dangerous thing, as the standard does not even require an implementation to have a consistent behaviour. See the dup.

Comment: @Olaf In fact, this could even be UB. If `a` has fewer elements than `level`, there's an out of bound access. Or if they were declared as: `int i = 0; int *a = &i; int *b = &i; int *c = &i;` and assuming `level`>0, there's also UB. I am sure many similar issues can be "invented" without seeing how the objects involved are declared.

Comment: @P.P. Actually assuming at least two of those pointers point to the same object, the behavior is undefined due to lack of sequence points.

Comment: @2501 ...which is what I just said in the comment above?

Comment: @P.P. Great, I see that now.

Comment: @P.P.: That is not a matter of "invention", but a very existent problem. No need to construct some UB here. But I well understand if one never worked with `volatile` lvalues, the problem seems to be far-fetched. For an embedded engineer, this is a very present issue.

Comment: @Olaf (Let's just assume you are the only one that knows about `volatile` qualified objects and put it aside). I am sure out-of-bounds access is also a very real issue for an embedded engineer. The point is that you are basing your argument on *what if it's volatile qualified?* and I am saying one could make similar argument for other cases too. Somehow *your* "what if" is a real issue whereas others are not?

Comment: @P.P.: Again: there is a significant difference assuming invalid code like you do or valid code! Feel free to revenge-DV, I'm out of this nonsense!

Answer (score 0):

The processing of above code goes as follows ...

First `0` is assigned to `c[i]` and then value of `c[i]` is assigned to `b[i]` and then the value of `b[i]` is assigned to `a[i]`.

So,overall to clear your concept,u should keep in mind from now that such assignment statements are evaluated from `right to left`.

Comment: This answer says "First 0 is assigned to ..." and "value of ... is assigned ...".  As I see it, there are no sequence points, so an optimizing compiler may re-order the assignments such as assigning `0` to `a[i]` and then the others.

Comment: *assignment statements are evaluated from right to left.* Incorrect. Right to left associativity has nothing to do with order of evaluation.